# Capstone install

Tags: docker, apk-tools

I want to build app from some source code, i run this in docker.

have this error

```
/vulnscan/src/disassembler.h:4:10: fatal error: capstone\capstone.h: No such file or directory
#include "capstone\capstone.h"
```

my test dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add git
RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add cmake
RUN apk add make
RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add clang
RUN apk add g++

RUN apk update
RUN apk add capstone-static
RUN apk add --upgrade capstone
```

Comment: Did you re-type the error message clumsily, or does it _actually_ use a backslash in the pathname?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, this from console